# Downloading an entire git repo to google colab

Tags: python, git, github, google-colaboratory, kaggle

There is a repository on github which contains image dataset in it. I want to download the entire repository on my google colab. But it does not seem to be working.
Here is what I have tried

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# kaggle is the folder that I created on my drive
!cd "drive/My Drive/kaggle"

# Downloading the repo on my drive
!git clone https://github.com/ardamavi/Sign-Language-Digits-Dataset.git
```

But I am getting an error

```
Cloning into 'Sign-Language-Digits-Dataset'...
fatal: I don't handle protocol '/content/https'
```

What was expected :

How can I download the entire repo on my drive or in the run time storage of google colab. Either of them will do.

Note : I tried all possible answers that I was getting as suggestion for this question but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `%cd` instead of `!cd`. Commands executed with `!` execute in a subshell, so you won't actually change the working directory for subsequent shell commands if you execute `cd` using `!`.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Can you also exlain about the erro ```I don't handle protocol '/content/https'```